# SQL Server RDS Web Edition Gives Access to Everything to New Users

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I'm currently setting up roles to give people limited access to our SQL Server RDS Web Edition Database.  I would need only insert and select privileges to one table.  However, it seems like new users are granted all privileges to all tables by default and I would have to run a recurring script to deny them from all new ones.  It seems like this logic is maybe AWS RDS centric as I had a SQL Server developer look at it.  Any suggestions how I can add a new user to deny them everything but one table by default?

Comment: Did someone grant permissions to the public role?

Comment: I don't believe so if I understand your answer.  I created this database with the default settings by AWS as an admin and I'm creating these logins and users with this admin role and nothing else.  Seems like they have access to all by default.